# How to perform polymorphic static dispatch in C++ based on runtime arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, compile-time, crtp

I would like to choose between multiple implementations of a class based on runtime arguments. This is straightforward with polymorphism and dynamic dispatch, as in the following example:

```
//demo.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A {
  virtual void print() { std::cout << name; }
  std::string name = "A";
};
struct A1 : public A { void print() { std::cout << name << "1"; } };
struct A2 : public A { void print() { std::cout << name << "2"; } };

struct B {
  virtual void print() { std::cout << name; }
  std::string name = "B";
};
struct B1 : public B { void print() { std::cout << name << "1"; } };
struct B2 : public B { void print() { std::cout << name << "2"; } };

void print_both(A* a, B* b) {
  a->print();
  std::cout << " ";
  b->print();
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::string arg1(argv[1]);
  std::string arg2(argv[2]);

  if (arg1 == "A1" && arg2 == "B1")
    print_both(new A1(), new B1());
  else if (arg1 == "A1" && arg2 == "B2")
    print_both(new A1(), new B2());
  else if (arg1 == "A2" && arg2 == "B1")
    print_both(new A2(), new B1());
  else if (arg1 == "A2" && arg2 == "B2")
    print_both(new A2(), new B2());
  else
    print_both(new A(), new B());
}
```

The example above produces the following output, which is as expected:

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 demo.cc
$ ./a.out A1 B1
A1 B1
$ ./a.out A1 B2
A1 B2
$ ./a.out A2 B1
A2 B1
$ ./a.out A2 B2
A2 B2
$ ./a.out A3 B3
A B
```

However, this quickly becomes unwieldy as the number of subclasses grows, or when adding another dimension (e.g., a third class `C` and associated subclasses). Suppose all possible `arg1` and `arg2` values are known at compile time. Is it possible to perform some templated static dispatch for all possible pairs? Ideally, it would look something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::string arg1(argv[1]);
  std::string arg2(argv[2]);

  print_both<arg1,arg2>();
}
```

Is there an easy and concise way to achieve this? I am open to using features from the latest C++ version.

**EDIT:** Here is a more concise version of what I am asking.

```
//demo.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

enum E { E1, E2, E3 };
template <E e> void print();
template <> void print<E1>() { std::cout << "E1" << std::endl; }
template <> void print<E2>() { std::cout << "E2" << std::endl; }
template <> void print<E3>() { std::cout << "E3" << std::endl; }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  //this works fine
  print<E1>();
  print<E2>();
  print<E3>();

  //is something like this possible?
  std::string arg(argv[1]);
  std::unordered_map<std::string,E> lut = {{"E1", E1}, {"E2", E2}, {"E3", E3}};
  auto e = lut[arg];
  print<e>(); //compiler error
}
```

Comment: Aside: 1) leaking memory 2) the runtime polymorphism case can/should be substantially simplified and be much easier to manage.

Comment: You might consider something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/5P3hK3aoo) as a 1st cut revision for the dynamic case.You could also try a lookup table approach. Doesn't answer your question about a better compile time approach, though.

Comment: Why not parse the arguments separately, then you just need 3 lines to parse the type of `A` and another three for `B`, these won't then need changing when you add `C`

Comment: Side note: If leaf classes are `final` and all code is visible to the compiler, then some compilers with optimizations enabled (sometimes requires LTO to also be enabled) can transform dynamic dispatch into static dispatch at compile time.

Comment: Polymorphic static dispatch based on runtime arguments/variables is **not possible**. For static dispatch to take place the compiler needs to know what member function will be called at compile time.

Comment: @MaBed If the possible runtime arguments are finite (e.g., `enum E { E1, E2, E3 };`), then you can enumerate all of the template specializations and generate if/else switching manually (or via macros) to call each one based on the arguments, as in the example. I was wondering if there was a better way to achieve this with template metaprogramming.

Comment: @crottyan Sure, but what you did in your example does not necessarily produces static dispatch. The calls `a->print()` and `b->print()` in `print_both` will probably still be dispatched dynamically - this depends solely on compiler, if it decides to roll out all 4 versions of the function (`A1, B1`; `A1, B2`; `A2, B1`; `A2, B2`). Also note, that if you just enumerate all the template specialization and generate `if/else`s manually, then you are basically programming your own dynamic dispatch (which will probably be slower than compiler's version).

Comment: The title is an oxymoron. If it is based on runtime arguments, then it is dynamic and not static, by definition.

Comment: "I would like to choose between multiple implementations of a class based on runtime arguments." It looks like you need a *factory*. It isn't at all clear why you need fiddling with "both" when you can clearly create instances of A and B independently. `print(create_A(arg1), create_B(arg2));`

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/412976/are-multiple-dynamic-dispatch-methods-possible

Answer (score 0):

If you want static dispatch, you could basically introduce one function template per type to be determined, parse one type per function and pass the remaining parameters on as template parameters.

```
#include <array>
#include <concepts>
#include <span>
#include <string_view>
...

template<char c>
struct A {
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << name << c;
    }
    std::string name = "A";
};

using A1 = A<'1'>;
using A2 = A<'2'>;

template<char c>
struct B {
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << name << c;
    }

    std::string name = "B";
};

using B1 = B<'1'>;
using B2 = B<'2'>;

namespace impl
{
constexpr size_t print_all_type_count = 2;

template<size_t N>
using print_all_arg = std::span<std::string_view, N>;

template<std::default_initializable AType, std::default_initializable BType>
void print_all2(print_all_arg<print_all_type_count - 2> args)
{
    static_assert(decltype(args)::extent == 0);

    AType a;
    BType b;

    a.print();
    std::cout << " ";
    b.print();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<std::default_initializable AType>
void print_all1(print_all_arg<print_all_type_count - 1> args)
{
    auto typeB = args[0];

    auto params = args.subspan<1>();

    if (typeB == "B1")
    {
        print_all2<AType, B1>(params);
    }
    else if (typeB == "B2")
    {
        print_all2<AType, B2>(params);
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("invalid value for typeB: ").append(typeB));
    }
}

} // namespace impl

void print_all(std::string_view typeA, std::string_view typeB)
{
    std::array typeNames{ typeB };

    std::span params = typeNames;

    if (typeA == "A1")
    {
        impl::print_all1<A1>(params);
    }
    else if (typeA == "A2")
    {
        impl::print_all1<A2>(params);
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("invalid value for typeA: ").append(typeA));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Expected exactly 2 parameters passed to the program, but got " << (argc - 1) << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    try
    {
        print_all(argv[1], argv[2]);
    }
    catch (std::exception const& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Now all you'd need to do to introduce an additional type would be to increase `print_all_type_count` by 1, change `print_all2` to a type parsing logic similar to `print_all1` which would call a function similar to the current `print_all2` but with an additionals. In addition to this you'd need to add an additional parameter to `print_all` and pass it to the initializer of `typeNames`.

Note though that the implementation using dynamic dispatch is far simpler to understand:

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void print() { std::cout << name; }
    std::string name = "A";
};
struct A1 : public A { void print() override { std::cout << name << "1"; } };
struct A2 : public A { void print() override { std::cout << name << "2"; } };

struct B {
    virtual ~B() = default;
    virtual void print() { std::cout << name; }
    std::string name = "B";
};
struct B1 : public B { void print() override { std::cout << name << "1"; } };
struct B2 : public B { void print() override { std::cout << name << "2"; } };

void print_both(A& a, B& b) {
    a.print();
    std::cout << " ";
    b.print();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

std::unique_ptr<A> create_a(std::string_view type)
{
    if (type == "A1")
    {
        return std::make_unique<A1>();
    }
    else if (type == "A2")
    {
        return std::make_unique<A2>();
    }
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string("invalid type name for A: ").append(type));
}

std::unique_ptr<B> create_b(std::string_view type)
{
    if (type == "B1")
    {
        return std::make_unique<B1>();
    }
    else if (type == "B2")
    {
        return std::make_unique<B2>();
    }
    throw std::runtime_error(std::string("invalid type name for B: ").append(type));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Expected exactly 2 parameters passed to the program, but got " << (argc - 1) << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    try
    {
        auto a = create_a(argv[1]);
        auto b = create_b(argv[2]);
        print_both(*a, *b);
    }
    catch (std::exception const& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is basically what I do now. I was wondering if, since all of the possible types are known at compile time, there is a way to use templates to avoid all the if/else checks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the goal but if you have a runtime parameter sooner or later you have to branch/switch on it at runtime. My version of LUT would be a kind of vtable which is basically dynamic dispatch.
For your "concise" version this can create the "LUT" without having to list all the template instantiations (this assumes that the possible enum values can be described with an integer sequence):

```cpp
enum E { E1 = 0, E2, E3 };
template <E e> void print();
template <> void print<E1>() { std::cout << "E1" << std::endl; }
// ...


// vtable type based on enum value (as int)
using lut_t = std::unordered_map<int,std::function<void()>>;

template<int... NUMBERS>
lut_t _createLut() {
    lut_t lut;
    ((lut[NUMBERS] = print<static_cast<E>(NUMBERS)>), ...);
    return lut;
}

template <int... Is>
lut_t createLut(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>) {
    return _createLut<Is...>();
}

int toEnumValue(const std::string& str) { /* ... */ }

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    auto lut = createLut(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 3>{});
    std::vector<std::string> args = {"E1", "E2", "E3"};
    lut[toEnumValue(args[0])]();
    lut[toEnumValue(args[1])]();
    lut[toEnumValue(args[2])]();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if it's relevant but Klaus Iglberger has a talk about "Value Semantics" (youtube, cppcon) where he used a vector of std::variants with overload sets and std::visit. With that solution he could avoid virtual functions and the objects didn't have to be allocated one by one (no pointers to object).

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing looks a lot like you're trying to do some variant of double-dispatch. You're trying to dispatch to one of many functions depending on the derived classes of two interface pointers. (If i'm wrong about this, then my whole answer does not apply.)

The simple form of that looks more like this:

```
struct A {virtual ~A() {}};
struct A1 : A { };
struct A2 : A {};

struct B {virtual ~B() {}};
struct B1 : B {  };
struct B2 : B { };

void print_both(A1*, B1*) {std::cout << "A1B1\n";}
void print_both(A1*, B2*) {std::cout << "A1B2\n";}
void print_both(A2*, B1*) {std::cout << "A2B1\n";}
void print_both(A2*, B2*) {std::cout << "A2B2\n";}

A* getA();
B* getB();

int main() {
    A* a = getA();
    B* b = getB();
    print_both(a, b); //compiler error!
}
```

It's worth a note that this situation arises from either poorly designed interfaces, or misuse of interfaces. As developers gain expertise and make and use interfaces better, they stop encountering this situation, which explains why the other answers didn't realize what you were referring to.

Unfortunately, there is no magic solution for double-dispatch in C++. The "fast" version is to integrate the calls into the classes themselves. This is super fast at runtime, but ugly and confusing in code. It also ties the implementation of the function directly into the class definitions themselves, requires interweaving of declarations and definitions in a specific order, and requires implementing O(n^2) methods. But it runs fast.

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() {}
    //Figure out which derived A to pass. We don't know the B yet.
    virtual void print_both(B*)=0; 
};
struct A1 : A {
    virtual void print_both(B*);
};
struct A2 : A {
    virtual void print_both(B*);
};

struct B {
    virtual ~B() {}
    //We know the A: now figure out the derived B to pass
    virtual void print_both(A1*)=0; 
    virtual void print_both(A2*)=0;
};
struct B1 : B { 
    virtual void print_both(A1*);
    virtual void print_both(A2*);
};
struct B2 : B {
    virtual void print_both(A1*);
    virtual void print_both(A2*);
};

void print_both(A1*, B1*) {std::cout << "A1B1\n";}
void print_both(A1*, B2*) {std::cout << "A1B2\n";}
void print_both(A2*, B1*) {std::cout << "A2B1\n";}
void print_both(A2*, B2*) {std::cout << "A2B2\n";}

void A1::print_both(B* b) { b->print_both_A1(); }
void A2::print_both(B* b) { b->print_both_A2(); }
void B1::print_both(A1* a) { print_both(a, *this); }
void B1::print_both(AB* a) { print_both(a, *this); }
void B2::print_both(A1* a) { print_both(a, *this); }
void B2::print_both(AB* a) { print_both(a, *this); }

int main() {
    A* a = getA();
    B* b = getB();
    a->print_both(b);
}
```

The other option is to have a dispatch function that is fundamentally a chain of `dynamic_casts`, which is similar to what you implemented. This separates the method from the class, which is good, but requires a set of checks for each possible overload, and is obnoxious to read and write. Theoretically this can be optimized by building some sort of `map<std::type_info, function>`, but that gets a little tricky, and is often slower when each parameter can only be a few types. Usually the simple form looks like this:

```
void print_both(A* a, B* b) {
    if (dynamic_cast<A1*>(a)) {
        if (dynamic_cast<B1*>(b) {
            print_both(dynamic_cast<A1*>(a), dynamic_cast<B1*>(b));
        else if (dynamic_cast<B2>(b) {
            print_both(dynamic_cast<A1*>(a), dynamic_cast<B2*>(b));
        else
            throw std::bad_cast();
    } else if (dynamic_cast<A2*>(a)) {
        if (dynamic_cast<B1>(b) {
            print_both(dynamic_cast<A2*>(a), dynamic_cast<B1*>(b));
        else if (dynamic_cast<B2*>(b) {
            print_both(dynamic_cast<A2*>(a), dynamic_cast<B2*>(b));
        else
            throw std::bad_cast();
    } else {
        throw std::bad_cast();
    }
}
```

For a larger number of arguments and possible derived types, you're right that neither scales well. So I've written a macro:

```
//requires that ALL parameters are raw pointers.
#define runtime_multi_dispatch(FUNC, ...) \
template<class...paramter_possibilities> \
struct FUNC##_dispatcherT { \
    template<class...unknownArgs> \
    static void call(unknownArgs*...unknown) { \
        static_assert(sizeof...(paramter_possibilities) == 0, "all parameters to dispatcher need to be `std::tuple<...>`"); \
    } \
}; \
template<class...known_args> \
struct FUNC##_dispatcherT<std::tuple<known_args...>> { \
    template<class placeholder=void> \
    static void call(known_args*...known) { \
        FUNC(known...); /*"error: no matching function for call to" means FUNC has non-pointer parameters.*/ \
    } \
}; \
template<class...known_args, class...next_arg_possibilities, class...unknown_param_possibilities_tuples> \
struct FUNC##_dispatcherT<std::tuple<known_args...>, std::tuple<next_arg_possibilities...>, unknown_param_possibilities_tuples...>  { \
    template<class nextArgT, class...unknownArgs> \
    static void call(known_args*...known, nextArgT* next, unknownArgs*...unknown) { \
        bool found = ((dynamic_cast<next_arg_possibilities*>(next) \
            ? (FUNC##_dispatcherT<std::tuple<known_args..., next_arg_possibilities>, unknown_param_possibilities_tuples...>::template call<unknownArgs...> \
                (known..., dynamic_cast<next_arg_possibilities*>(next), unknown...), true) \
            : false) || ...); \
        if (!found) throw std::bad_cast(); \
    } \
}; \
constexpr struct { \
    template<class...unknownArgs> \
    void operator()(unknownArgs*...unknown) const { \
        FUNC##_dispatcherT<std::tuple<>, __VA_ARGS__>::call(unknown...); \
    } \
} FUNC##_dispatcher
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9c1b857dbe708f1

And then usage is fairly straightforward:

```
//This defines an `print_both_dispatcher` functionoid
//where the first parameter's derived type is either A1* or A2*
//and the second parameter's derived type is either B1* or B2*
//and calls `print_both` with those derived parameters.
runtime_multi_dispatch(print_both, std::tuple<A1,A2>, std::tuple<B1,B2>);

int main() {
    A* a = getA();
    B* b = getB();
    print_both_dispatcher(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments already provided, I m not sure static binding would be truly achievable if the whole thing is driven by a parameter value, known at runtime.
Still to stay on your vibe.
I saw your code was using value discriminant for selecting the specilized templates..
in my opinion, this was doomed as soon as you save it all in a map<string, enum E>

but could be usable if you use real type like class E1; class E2; and class E3;
if you allow that step away, then what we renamed previously "static binding" to type specialized logic then your code could look like this with std::variant/std::visit

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <variant>
#include <map>

// helper type for the visitor #4
template<class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
// explicit deduction guide (not needed as of C++20)
template<class... Ts>
overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

class E;
class E1{};
class E2{};
class E3{};

template <typename E> void print();
template <> void print<E1>() { std::cout << "E1" << std::endl; }
template <> void print<E2>() { std::cout << "E2" << std::endl; }
template <> void print<E3>() { std::cout << "E3" << std::endl; }

void print(std::variant<E1, E2, E3> e)
{
std::visit(overloaded{
        [](E1 arg) { print<E1>(); },
        [](E2 arg) {  print<E2>(); },
        [](E3 arg) {  print<E3>(); },
    }, e);
}
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::variant<E1, E2, E3>> lut = {{"E1", E1()}, {"E2", E2()}, {"E3", E3()}};
    auto e = lut["E1"];    
    print(e);
}
```